# maps, rails 4.2, javascript, mouse-over, only working once (or twice) .. then after reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, maps

I did a map on rails 4.2. Javascript to add pins, and some information when mouse-over the pin, like so;

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          title: "title_x",
```

..
also, i added an infowindow for each marker, like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {    infoWindow.setContent("contentx");                         
infowindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);}
})(marker, i));
```

Problem 1: When i do 'mouseover' over the pins, it shows me the TITLE. That's good. But, it does so only one or two or three times - then nothing. When reloading the page, or - opening another tab or, after going back to another program (changing the window) - it works, again, once or twice.

Problem 2: the infowindow does not open at all, say, when i 'click' onto the pin, nothing happens.

- not sure if these are the same problems or two issues.

Reading a lot of answers in SO, i tried these things, but not change.

a/ delete the turbolinks-line in application.js
Also: adding this: data-no-turbolink (into the navigation-link, into the div that contains the map)

b/ in the 'main' javascript file:
    $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
      loadScript();
    });

c/ in this file that shows the map):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {initialize();}); // ADDED
  window.nearbys= <%=raw @myparams.to_json %>; 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

When i added the line (ADDED), at least, it showed the map and pins (before, no reaction). Even that it seems for me, that two times the same instruction is executed - anyhow, it works.

Such, my problem: 
- what i can read in SO, it seems, that people disabled the turbolinks - i did, no change.
- also, it seems that something is executed once after reloading (for me, it is happening a few times? but that maybe depends on other issues?)

For any link (besides the solutions that i tried and described above) i would be very glad.
also, i would be happy not to use turbolinks at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found something that worked myself.

Issue a/, the not-updated title of the pins: There was a SO article, that said: issue if working on Firefox. The latest Google API has a bug. It is said to work with 3.16, but, that API is not supported any more. - no issue, so using Chrome or IE - and it worked: mouseover a pin, and the title is shown (the first, second .. just any time mouseover).

Issue b/ not working infowindow: very simple this code

```
@users = User.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
  marker.lat user.latitude
  marker.lng user.longitude
  marker.title = "title" // ADDED
  marker.infowindow = "iw" // ADDED
end
```

as shown in https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails, and very clear visible in all its components (model, view, control, and JS) here: https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps (just saw the codes, did not try it b/c different ruby version and whatever problem .. but following the code example)
- and added (ADDED) a title, and infowindow - and it just worked as thought it should.

even nicer :))
issue a/ seemed to be 'cured' by it: (by the users' behaviour, actually, in usual cases may i think): users are used to 'click' onto the pin, and the infowindow appears. That seems to fire the JS/load/page-refresh (whatever it is) in Firefox. That is - the next mouseover (showing the title) will work. Fun, isn't it.

And thanks to the creater of gmap4rails, it's a fine thing.